How can I get the Capacity Weight of a record?
In Omni-Channel, I'm setting a flow to assign a pending record to an available agent which still has interruptible capacity.
Currently, I calculated the available capacity of that agent. I need to know that record's capacity weight to compare if agent have enough capacity. How can I achieve this case. Thank you!
